# is there a way to prevent views from beeing scaled in android?

Tags: android, view, scaling

I have a custom view that is scaling to 200% when the user clicks on it.
Now I want to prevent some controls/views in that custom view from beeing scaled.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigating I think there is no way to programmatically freeze a view as described. As a dirty workaround you can put the view that should not be scaled in another container that is positioned over the scaled view.